# what exactly does a generic extending from a class mean?

Tags: java, generics, extends

what does this exactly mean?

```
public class Deck<T extends Card>
```

What does the T extends Card mean? Does this imply something about the class Card?

thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It constrains the type parameter ("T") to be `Card` or a subtype of `Card`.

So if

```
public class FancyCard extends Card
```

... then it is a valid type for use with `Deck` (i.e. `Deck<FancyCard>`). However, `String` obviously does not extend `Card`, so `Deck<String>` will not compile.

Comment: oh i see. so in this case, does that also mean the class Deck inherits the methods/fields of the class Card also? thanks!

Comment: Nope. The generics are used to define a "uses" relationship, not any kind of "is a". The Deck's public interface does not change, except for the specification of parameters and/or return types. Generics are not related to inheritance in that way.

Comment: In fact, Deck's implementation doesn't change either.

Comment: thanks, i guess it seemed a bit tricky when i saw <T extends Card>. i guess it doesn't mean the same thing as Deck extends Card